# Error while running built value generator

Tags: flutter, built-value, dart-build

I got an error while trying to use built value generator

This was the error that i got.

```
[INFO] Running build...
[INFO] Generating SDK summary.
[SEVERE] built value generator:built value on lib/json_parsing.dart:
Bad state: Unexpected diagnostics:
C:\src\flutter\bin\cacheldart-sdk\lib\core\uri.dart:3259:39 - Expected an identifier.
[SEVERE] built_value_generator:built_value on lib/json_parsing.dart:

Bad state: Unexpected diagnostics:
C:\src\Flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\lib\core uri.dart:3259:39 - Expected an identifier.

[SEVERE] built_value_generator:built_value on lib/json_parsing.dart:

Bad state: Unexpected diagnostics:
C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\lib\coreluri.dart:3259:39 - Expected an identifier.
```

the class which i was using running the built value generator on

```
import 'package:built_value/built_value.dart';

part 'src/json_parsing.g.dart';

abstract class Article implements Built<Article, ArticleBuilder> {
  Article._();
  factory Article([void Function(ArticleBuilder) updates]) = _$Article;
}
```

Comment: I were facing the same issue maybe 'cause of (https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/63556). So added ```dependency_overrides:
  analyzer: '0.39.14'``` to ```pubspec.yaml``` and it builds successfully.

Comment: Where should this be added in dev dependecy or dependencies

Comment: ```pubspec.yaml```

Comment: Dependencies or dev_dependencies??

Comment: Neither. Its ```dependency_overrides:```

Comment: This worked for me... thanks

Comment: flutter clean work for me

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned by @Mohammad on the comments, and from [this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/63556#issuecomment-678748658), just add this to `pubspec.yaml`:

```
dependency_overrides:
  analyzer: '0.39.14'
```

Note, this is a sibling of `dependencies` and `dev_dependencies`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like build_runner version 1.10.1 pinned the version of analyzer to 0.39.14.

Try to update build_runner: `build_runner: ^1.10.1` without adding dependency_overrides: and see.